# how to correct summary.factor error in stable isotope analysis in R

Tags: r, model

I wanted to analyse my stable isotope data using stable isotope analysis in R (SIAR). When running the model using the command:

```
model1 <- siarmcmcdirichletv4(data, sources, tef, concdep=0, 500000, 50000)
```

as advised in the SIAR Manual for Ecologists, I got this message:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L,  : max not meaningful for factors.
```

Can you please advise me how to proceed from here?

Comment: try and make this [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I guess there is a variable in your data that is supposed to be numeric, but is actually a factor (due to a typo in the file or something like that). Check `str(data)`, `str(sources)` and `str(tef)`.

Answer (score 0):

SIAR only works with numerical group names, and as far as I remember, they have to start at 1 and run in sequential order in the data file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error message using SIAR in R. My problem was caused by the fact that my files were saved as .csv, whereas they need to be in .txt.